# Uniform convergence of $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ Where $f(\sigma) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(n)/n^\sigma$

Tags: uniform-convergence, riemann-zeta, sequence-of-function

Here $\mu(n)$ is Möbius function.

Note: this question is substantially changed after comments from Daniel and Reuns. The original question did not make any sense. The domain of function is changed to real numbers because, initially I was conflating between boundedness and convergence. I had wrongly assumed 
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(n)/n^s$ was bounded on the like $s = 1+ it$. It is not. as a result, the answer may seem disconnected.

There are two approaches one can take to find where $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(n)/n^\sigma$ is uniformly convergent.

1) Because absolute convergence implies uniform convergence, the series of functions must be uniformly convergent for interval $\sigma \ge 1+\epsilon$. The $\epsilon$ is needed to make the domain compact - which is needed for uniform continuity.

2) Further, the norm $| f_n - f | < \epsilon $ where $\epsilon$ does not depend on $\sigma$ according to the following from Titchmarsh:

[image: Titchmarsh’s Theory of Riemann Zeta Function Lemma 3.12]

Does this make sense?

Comment: The series converges absolutely for $\operatorname{Re} s > 1$, not on the line $\operatorname{Re} s = 1$. Thus you can only conclude that it converges uniformly on $\operatorname{Re} s \geqslant 1 + \varepsilon$, for every $\varepsilon > 0$. And indeed it doesn't converge uniformly on the closed half-plane $\operatorname{Re} s \geqslant 1$. Each partial sum of the series is bounded there, but $1/\zeta(s)$ isn't.

Comment: You’re right about the absolute convergence! But $1/\zeta(s)$ (the function) must be bounded as $\zeta(s)$ has no zeroes on the line $s=1$, And if the function is bounded and analytic then so should the sum be by Lemma 3.12. No? Will the result from Lemma 3.12 mitigate this and extend uniform convergence to $s = 1+it$ - irrespective of RH being true or false?

Comment: That $\zeta(s)$ has no zeros on the line $\operatorname{Re} s = 1$ means $1/\zeta(s)$ is holomorphic on some neighbourhood of the closed half-plane, but not that it is bounded on the closed half-plane. That would imply $\inf_{t\in \mathbb{R}} \lvert \zeta(1+it)\rvert > 0$, but this is not the case. (If memory serves, Bohr and Landau proved that in 1913 or 1914.)

Comment: I’ll need to digest that. But as $\sum_n \frac{\mu(n)}{n}=0$ can we have $\sum_n \frac{\mu(n)}{n^\sigma}$ uniformly convergent on interval $\sigma \in [1,\infty)$ (Considering only real domain)?

Comment: Yes, and since the series converges on the whole line the convergence is uniform on $$M(\varepsilon) = \{s : \operatorname{Re} s \geqslant 1 + \varepsilon \lor (\lvert\operatorname{Im} s\rvert \leqslant 1/\varepsilon \land \operatorname{Re} s \geqslant 1)\}$$ for every $\varepsilon > 0$. One just has to exclude the "corners".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something that you are missing but it is hard to tell what.

> Under the RH, $\sum_n \mu(n) n^{-s}$ converges for $\Re(s) > 1/2$. $\tag{1}$

Let $\Re(s)>a>1/2$.

By partial summation $(1)$ implies that it is $= \sum_n (\sum_{m\le n} \mu(m)m^{-a})(n^{a-s}-(n+1)^{a-s})$ which converges absolutely and hence $(1)$ converges locally uniformly on $\Re(s) >1/2$, uniformly on $\Re(s)>a, |arg(s-a)|\le \pi/2-r$. We know that it doesn't converge uniformly on $\Re(s) > a$ because $1/\zeta(s)$ is unbounded on $\Re(s)=1$ (it follows from the Euler product and that the $\log p$ are $\Bbb{Q}$-linearly independent).

The proof of $(1)$ is in the last chapter of Titchmarsh, it is based on the same argument of shifting to the left $$\int_{2-iT}^{2+iT} \frac{x^{z-s}}{(z-s)\zeta(z)}dz=2i\pi \sum_{n\le x}\mu(n)n^{-s}+O(x^{2-s+\epsilon}/T)$$ $$=2i\pi Res(\frac{x^{z-s}}{(z-s)\zeta(z)})+\int_{a-iT}^{a+iT} \frac{x^{z-s}}{(z-s)\zeta(z)}dz\pm \int_{a\pm iT}^{2\pm iT} \frac{x^{z-s}}{(z-s)\zeta(z)}dz$$

As in the proof of the PNT, we need a bound for $\frac1{\zeta(s)}$ which will be $$\frac1{\zeta(s)}=O(t^\epsilon)$$ (it follows from $\log \zeta(2+it)=O(1)$, the density of zeros and $ (\log \zeta(s))'' = \sum_\rho \frac1{(s-\rho)^2} = o( \log s)$)

For the vertical part we obtain $\int_{a-iT}^{a+iT} \frac{x^{z-s}}{(z-s)\zeta(z)}dz=O(T^\epsilon x^{a-s})$.

We'll take $T=x^3$ so that $O(x^{2-s+\epsilon}/T)=o(1),\int_{a\pm iT}^{2\pm iT} \frac{x^{z-s}}{(z-s)\zeta(z)}dz=o(1)$ and the result follows

$$2i\pi \sum_{n\le x}\mu(n)n^{-s}=2i\pi Res(\frac{x^{z-s}}{(z-s)\zeta(z)})+o(1)$$

Comment: If $f_n$ is bounded and $\lim f_n$ converges uniformly then $\lim f_n$ is bounded